# Hash a File Line By Line

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that will read down a .txt file that the user supplies and have it output a list of hashes. This is what I have so far, I can't figure out how to get it to open the file and hash individual words. Instead, it hashes the name of the file.

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < string.h >
#include "md5.h"//char *md5(const char *str, int length);
#include < stdlib.h >

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) //argc: # of arguments argv: inputand utput
{
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fp) {
    printf("Can't open %s for reading\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  FILE * out;

  if (argc != 3) //(argc < 2 || argc > 3)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s word_to_hash [output_file]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }


  out = fopen(argv[2], "w");

  FILE * fpout;
  if (argc == 3) {
    fpout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!fpout) {
      printf("Can't open %s for writing\n", argv[2]);
      exit(1);
    }
  }


  char line[100];
  while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
    if (argc == 3) fclose(fpout);

    if (argc != 3) //(argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
      fprintf("%s", "r");//printf("Usage: %s word_to_hash [output_file]\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
    }

    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (argc == 3) {
      out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
      if (!out) {
        printf("Can't open %s for writing.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(2);
      }
    }
    else
      out = stdout;

    char * hash = md5(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    fprintf(out, "%s\n", hash);

    if (argc == 3)
      fprintf(fpout, "%s", line);
    else
      printf("%s", line);
  }

  // Close file
  fclose(fp);

}
```

//clang hashpass.c md5.c -o hashp -l crypto

//./hashp words.txt output.txt

^these are what I'm using to compile and run the program respectively. Words.txt is the separate file I'm trying to get my code to read. Any help with being ale to open the file correctly would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your indentation; it's incredibly broken.

Comment: Tip: test `if (argc > 1)` before `fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");`.

Comment: It's still giving me the same hash: 738f8aa27f81b113d9bf77e5d5194065 @chux

Comment: `hash = md5(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]))` hashes `argv[1]`.  If code is to "hash individual words", I'd expect `hash = md5(line, strlen(line))` or something that looks for `"words" in `line`.

Comment: You only need open a file once to write to it. You are confusing yourself with the multiple tests for `argc == 3` and `argc != 3` and the unnecessary multiple calls to `fopen` and `fclose`.

Comment: When having trouble: simplify until things work and then one-by-one add the complexity back in.

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem with your code is -- it's more of a jumble of things you thought sounded like a good idea to try, so you added them, compiled, it failed, you changed a few things, compiled, it failed, (and then you repeated until you were so hopelessly lost you needed to ask for help) -- that's not how you program...

Programming, each expression has meaning and you have to understand exactly what each does if you ever hope to write a program that accomplishes anything. The way you do that is you pick up a pencil and piece of paper and outline the steps that need to occur in order to complete your task. You then research what features the language provides to let you accomplish each individual step and you learn how to properly use each feature by referring to the documentation (be it the Linux man page, the MSDN page or the C-Standard for each function you have decided to use).

You do all of this **before** picking up the keyboard and starting to peck away at your code. While it may see like this approach is requires a lot of effort and time -- how much time have you wasted with the *"guess, compile, fail, repeat"* approach? A proper approach will actually shorten the amount of time it takes to go from start to finish.

Alright, with that background, it is plainly obvious you need a bit of help to get pointed in the right direction. As you have probably guessed by now, it makes no sense to make 3 calls to `out = fopen(argv[2], "w");` in your code and it is downright bewildering why you would read a line from `fp` and then immediately close `fpout` (thought it has never been used), e.g.

```
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        if (argc == 3) fclose(fpout);
```

Further, you have sprinkled into your logic either writing to `argv[2]` or `stdout`. For code of this size, that is what simple shell *redirection* is for (it works the same on Linux, Windows and Mac). Don't worry about opening an output file, simply write to `stdout` and if you want to output to a file, then *redirect* the output to a file on the command line, e.g.

*Reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout`*

```
$ yourprogram < somefile
```

*Reading from `stdin` and redirecting `stdout` to a file*

```
$ yourprogram < somefile > output file
```

You do the same to read from a file you open with `fopen (name, "r")`, you simply remove the initial `'<'`.

Approaching input and output in that manner simplifies reading and writing and let's you concentrate on the main objective for your code.

With that in mind, you can remove most of what you have in your code and simply open the file given as `argv[1]` for reading (or if no argument is given, simply read from `stdin` by default). The following example does just that and uses `<openssl/md5.h>` for the MD5 hash since we have no way of knowing what your `"md5.h"` contains. Additionally, the following example will hash every *line* in the input if `HASHLINE` is defined (by simply including `-DHASHLINE` in your compiler options) or it will hash each *word* by default if `HASHLINE` is not defined. The example was coded with the alternative because it is completely unclear whether you are trying to hash each *word* or *line* as you use both in your description and variable names.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one - don't skimp */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char word[MAXC] = "";                       /* word/line buffer */
    unsigned char hash[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH] = ""; /* buffer to hold hash */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin; /* file or stdin */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

#ifndef HASHLINE
    while (fscanf (fp, "%s", word) == 1) {  /* read word at a time */
        const char *fmt = "%-16s : ";       /* printf (fmt, ...) for words */
#else
    while (fgets (word, MAXC, fp)) {        /* read line at a time */
        const char *fmt = "%-32s : ";       /* printf (fmt, ...) for lines */
        word[strcspn (word, "\n")] = 0;     /* remove trailing '\n' */
#endif
        size_t len = strlen (word);         /* get length of word/line */
        int index = 0,                      /* index for output hex char */
            n = MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH;          /* md5 hash length */

        MD5 ((const unsigned char *)word, len, hash);   /* compute hash */
        printf (fmt, word);                 /* output word/line */
        while (n--)
            printf ("%02x", hash[index++]); /* output hash */
        putchar ('\n');                     /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */
}
```

(**note:** if you are unsure how to compile the code, let me know what compiler you are using and I'm happy to provide a compile string)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

Hash each line, compiling with `HASHLINE` defined, e.g. by passing the `-DHASHLINE` command line option to your compiler:

```
$ ./bin/wordsmd5sslline dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale                   : 3495386196b8aef7d65ae857a8a5f4dc
Of Captain Jack Sparrow          : 225057b50358205942eafa11a35e4028
A Pirate So Brave                : 3f3498d45e5f3be24ae264768dcbb4c8
On the Seven Seas.               : 390ab96392602d0e78ae28b30444481f
```

Hash each word (default if `HASHLINE` not defined):

```
$ ./bin/wordsmd5ssl dat/captnjack.txt
This             : 77631ca4f0e08419b70726a447333ab6
is               : a2a551a6458a8de22446cc76d639a9e9
a                : 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
tale             : 4d3debafdd402130036512d2af7f3661
Of               : cdb81f21e18b5679feb341b73957f082
Captain          : bc9d8ff48a9f3679ea9e4b2ca69b535b
Jack             : 40687c8206d15373954d8b27c6724f62
Sparrow          : ef5a30521df4c0dc7568844eefe7e7e3
A                : 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
Pirate           : 95aa99a5810a35a3659d5322fe4bad00
So               : e2e0ab9c9510bf61fd17296bae8d3d24
Brave            : 8d091597127cc044520e13fae3a3af59
On               : 521c36a31c2762741cf0f8890cbe05e3
the              : 8fc42c6ddf9966db3b09e84365034357
Seven            : 12e67aac3e7f9227cc35f8f047d7dc74
Seas.            : 19246a3b564662c1fd25c64a1d1661ef
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.